# Releasing object being returned the right way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

If I am creating an object inside of a function and returning it, when/where should I release this object? Here is an example where I am creating an object.

```
- (NSDictionary*) sampleFunction
{
    NSMutableDictionary* state = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    [state setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:self.a]  forKey:@"a"];
    [state setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:self.b] forKey:@"b"];
    [state setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:self.c] forKey:@"c"];

    return state;
}
```

Additional question: In order to avoid memory leaks am I also supposed to release the NSNumbers allocated here as well? What would this code look like without memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should go to this guide for all the rules:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

...don't take what people say on here as gospel. There are some exceptions and odd rules the guide I linked to above will clarify.

Now, relating to your example: *broadly* speaking, every time you `alloc` something you must release it. When you're returning a value from a method, it should be `autoreleased` (99% of the time. There are a couple of exceptions: see, nothing is every easy!). Apple provide some auto-released methods for convenience - `NSNumber` has one of these.

I'm going to show you your code above, but rewritten to use those autoreleased methods:

```
- (NSDictionary*) sampleFunction
{
    NSMutableDictionary* state = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];

    [state setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.a]  forKey:@"a"];
    [state setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.b] forKey:@"b"];
    [state setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.c] forKey:@"c"];

    return state;
}
```

As I mentioned, you can also use `autorelease` with `alloc/init`:

```
NSMutableDictionary* state = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5]autorelease];
```

Again, the Apple document I've linked to above is the **best** place to go for answers to memory management questions.